# What data is being fetched from 'data' variable in 's'?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand NER, I see following code line, I am not able to figure out meaning of this line,

```
s = self.data[self.data["Sentence #"] == "Sentence: {}".format(self.n_sent)]
```

I am reading code from,
https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/introduction-named-entity-recognition-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `n_sent=1`

```
"Sentence: {}".format(self.n_sent)
```

will produce string `Sentence: 1` and will match it against the first column using

```
self.data["Sentence #"] == "Sentence: {}".format(self.n_sent)
```

and finally slice the dataframe using boolean mask wherever the condition matches to get data of particular sentence

```
s = self.data[self.data["Sentence #"] == "Sentence: {}".format(self.n_sent)]
```

and further the `n_sent+=1` will increment and will repeat the process to get the next sentence